# Angular JS md-datepicker

Tags: php, sql, angularjs, datepicker

I want to insert my `md-datepicker` value into PHP database but while inserting the error is that the data is undefined, in case of Date. How should I insert the value of `md-datepicker` inside the PHP Page.

reservation.html

```
<div id="reservation" class="reservation" ng-controller="ReservationController">
    <h2><i>Reservations</i></h2>
    <div class="datepicker" ng-controller="DatePickerController">
    <section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" layout-wrap required>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDate" md-placeholder="Enter Date"  md-open-on-focus required></md-datepicker>
    </div>
        <input type='text' class='myBox' placeholder="Enter your name..." ng-model="username">
        <input type='text' class='myBox' style="margin-left:100px;" placeholder="Enter your mobile number..." ng-model="mobile_number">
    <div class="book">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="insertData()">Book Your Meal</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

datepicker.js

```
app.controller('DatePickerController',['$scope',function($scope){
  this.myDate = new Date();
  var [] newDate = ctrl.MyDate.Split(T);
  string finalDate = newdate[0];
  $scope.myDate = finalDate;
  this.isOpen = false;
}]);
```

reservation.js

```
app.controller("ReservationController",['$scope', '$http', function ($scope,$http) {

$scope.insertData = function(){
  //window.location.href='index.html#/menu';
  $http.post('database/push_Reservation.php',{'username':$scope.username, 'mobile_number': $scope.mobile_number, 'mydate': $scope.myDate})
    .then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}]);
```

Comment: You are trying to access scopes from diferent controllers. You can't do that in Angular in your case (it depends on the hierarchy).

Comment: @nicolascolman rest other element values are being inserted except the date.

Comment: Did you try replacing ctrl.myDate for myDate in the html markup?

Comment: yeah I did try it @nicolascolman

Comment: The datepicker is in a child controller. I just posted a solution.

Answer (score 0):

DatepickerController:

```
app.controller('DatePickerController',['$scope',function($scope){
  this.myDate = new Date();
  var [] newDate = ctrl.MyDate.Split(T);
  string finalDate = newdate[0];
  $scope.myDate = finalDate;
  this.isOpen = false;
  $scope.$emit('response', $scope.myDate);
}]);
```

ReservationController:

```
app.controller("ReservationController",['$scope', '$http', function ($scope,$http) {
$scope.$on('response', function (evnt, data) {
    $scope.myDate = data;
  });
$scope.insertData = function(){
  //window.location.href='index.html#/menu';
  $http.post('database/push_Reservation.php',{'username':$scope.username, 'mobile_number': $scope.mobile_number, 'mydate': $scope.myDate})
    .then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}]);
```